# How to place a texture at the pole of a sphere?

Tags: webgl, three.js

Even with high resolution textures (4k*2k) of Earth the mapping of the poles is distorted. Is it possible to place a square texture with the middle directly at the poles of a sphere with THREE.js and rotate accordingly?

Example map: http://rapidfire.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?mosaic=Arctic.2012154.terra.4km.jpg

Sorry, no code, looking for a starting point.

Comment: Do you have a texture like that for the 6 sides?

Comment: Yes, could be prepared. Cubemap? Also, I don't care if lower latitudes are black.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should 'correct' your rectangular texture to avoid the distortion on the poles.

This link might be of help for that: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/texture_colour/texturemap/

Comment: Neat. Theoretically you could do that in the shader.

Answer (score 0):

In [Cesium](http://cesium.agi.com), a WebGL globe & map engine, we fixed the poles by creating a screen-space quad over where each pole will be, and using a shader to render the pole correctly.  The code is in [this pull request](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/42).  We don't yet offer inlay high-res images, but that's coming.